# Fully managed MP3 decoder other than NLayer

Tags: c#, .net, codec

I'm running a .NET application on Windows server platform, trying to convert `MP3`  streams to wave streams and vice versa. Since there's no `ACM MP3` decoder installed on the system, I need to use some fully managed `MP3` decoder such as `NLayer`. But some difficulties were met for me using `NLayer`, so is there any other fully managed `MP3` decoder I can try?

Comment: Check out [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore), also don't forget _GIYF_